# "Voting corrected" number seems to be incorrect at first

Tags: bug, reputation, serial-voting

A few days ago I got hit by a serial voting reversal. When I first visited by reputation tab, it said -230:

[image: Screenshot]

However, when I now visit my reputation tab, it shows -120:

[image: Screenshot]

The correct number is -120. So, where did 230 come from?

---

This was also posted on [languagedesign.meta](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/344/13) (by another user who had the same issue as me - except their one showed -726 which then turned into -50) a few minutes ago, but I felt it would be better placed here.

Comment: Possibly a rep cap thing?

Comment: @Laurel no, I had only gone over the rep cap once in the previous month before that, and it was only by 20 rep.

Comment: Maybe the algorithm detected a high number of suspicious upvotes by a single user in a short period of time, and then a human intervened and corrected some of them. If another user upvotes (or downvotes!) a bunch of posts by another user in a short period of time, all bets are off - all or some of them could be undone by the system, by a moderator, or a mix, and possibly in multiple steps (leading to changes you'd see in your reputation history at any given time). See [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/1274780)

Comment: @Stuckat1337 but my reputation was still the same. If a mod had intervened, my rep would have gone up by 110 when they intervened, but that didn't happen. It was always 120 below what it had been.

Comment: Gremlins? Who knows? Note that a rep recalculation is separate. So it may have happened _after_ the other 110 rep was un-revoked, but before a rep recalc actually affected your global reputation. In other words, the math applied to your reputation tab and to your total reputation are disconnected, and it's likely that you just saw them in an in-between state.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 maybe, but what's the likelihood that it's happened *twice* in a few days on some small sites? And if the number (-726) stated in the second one (on languagedesign) was accurate, that would have been one upvote on almost every single one of that user's answers. For that reason, I think this is a bug.

Comment: It probably happens _all the time_, it's just that, usually, people either don't notice or are satisfied when the correction and their reputation line up. All the sites use the same software so I'm not sure what kind of sinister thing you expect would explain this situation for you and one other user. Your reputation is correct now, right? You understand that some system process made a change to your reputation, and that it may impact _different places_ your reputation is displayed at _different times_, yes? What other explanation are you looking for? If it fixed itself, what is there to fix?

Comment: @Stuckat1337 yes, it's correct now, but I just want to know why it wasn't correct before. That's it. If it was just a change that impacted different systems at different times, that's fine, I just want an answer that I can accept.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 also, there is absolutely no way the -726 was correct, since that wouldn't be possible in one day (maximum is 40*10=400), and the process runs every day, so it would have caught it on the first day. This means it *must* be a big, which I would like fixed.

Comment: Technically it would be -480, right? 400 from the removed upvotes and 80 from the new downvotes. Still nowhere close to 726.

Comment: I guess by "mods" they meant "staff", because there are currently no mods on LanguageDesign.SE due to no election yet, but even elected mods cannot revoke votes directly, only indirectly by deleting the account. And while there is a daily cap of 200 from voting, accepted answers and bounties are exempted, though I don't think there's a bounty other than the current one...

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. yeah, the point still stands, it wasn't staff, or the fact the I hit the rep cap. It's definitely a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the [linked post](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/344/89) on PLDI Meta. A second correction was applied today on PLDI SE, and the same issue occurred:

[image: reversal +30 Voting corrected, +6 Serial voting was reversed]

The dropdown reputation tab shows +6, while the reputation page shows +30 for the same event. The numbers here are smaller, so fewer votes were reversed, and this gives a clue about what might be the cause of the issue.

A reversed downvote is worth +2, so three reversed downvotes makes +6. On the other hand, if the reputation page incorrectly counts them as if they are upvotes, then it would make sense for three upvotes to make +30. So I suspect the the dropdown tab is correct, but the reputation page is incorrectly counting reversed downvotes as if they are upvotes.

I'm not sure how this could account for the discrepancy between −50 and −726, but perhaps the root cause is something similar, i.e. one type of reversed vote being counted as if it is a different type of vote.

---

**Edit:** as of 25th June, the −726 and +30 values are now correctly showing as −50 and +6 on the reputation page respectively. I can't say on what date the correct numbers appeared, but either the bug has been fixed, or perhaps it's a caching issue.

Comment: I'm not too sure about this. For me, the reversed votes were all upvotes (12 of them), and it somehow showed -230.

Comment: Regarding your latest revision, for me it showed the correct number after I refreshed the page. So, I don't think this is indicative of the jug having been fixed.